# What is the difference between scipy.signal.spectrogram and scipy.signal.stft?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

The functions 
`spicy.signal.spectrogram`:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html

and 
`spicy.signal.stft`:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html 
seem to do a very similar thing.

What is the difference between the two functions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Tl;dr**: If I write it with the ouput given by the SciPy documentation: `Sxx = Zxx ** 2`

**Explanation**:
Spectrogram and Short Time Fourier Transform are two different object, yet they are really close together.

> The short-time Fourier transform (STFT), is a Fourier-related
>   transform used to determine the sinusoidal frequency and phase content
>   of local sections of a signal as it changes over time. In practice,
>   the procedure for computing STFTs is to divide a longer time signal
>   into **shorter segments of equal length** and then compute the Fourier
>   transform separately on each shorter segment. This reveals the Fourier
>   spectrum on each shorter segment. One then usually plots the changing
>   spectra as a function of time. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform)

On the other hand,

> A spectrogram is a visual representation of the spectrum of
>   frequencies of a signal as it varies with time. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram)

The spectrogram basically cuts your signal in small windows, and display a range of colors showing the intensity of this or that specific frequency. Exactly as the STFT. In fact it's using the STFT.

**Now, for the difference**, by definition, the spectrogram is squared magnitude of the short-time Fourier transform (STFT) of the signal `s(t)`:

`spectrogram(t, w) = |STFT(t, w)|^2`

The example shown at the bottom of the `scipy.signal.stft` page shows:

```py
>>> plt.pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Zxx), vmin=0, vmax=amp)
```

It's working and you can see a color scale. But it's a linear one, because of the `abs` operation.

In reality, to get the real spectrogram, one should write:

```py
>>> plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Zxx ** 2, vmin=0, vmax=amp)
```

Comment: Minor nitpick, but shouldn't that last term be the magnitude squared, and not just squared?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question perfectly but in the case of the L2 norm, if I write X = [x1, x2, x3,...] as a vector, X^2 = X.X (dotproduct) = |x1| * |x1| + |x2| * |x2| + |x3| * |x3| +... = |x1|^2 + |x2|^2 + |x3|^2 +... = |X|^2
So in the end it's the same!

Comment: My question is if the data is complex. You mention the spectrogram as the magnitude squared of the STFT but then show in the pcolormesh command just taking Zxx ** 2, whereas I think maybe it should be np.abs(Zxx)**2?

Comment: Both functions have an optional parameter to chose what is the output, for `spectrogram`: `scaling{ ‘density’, ‘spectrum’ }`, for `stft`: `scaling: {‘spectrum’, ‘psd’}`, so both amplitude and power can be directly obtained in both functions. I believe `spectrogram` has no inverse to reconstruct the signal, while `stft` has `istft`. The reason might be [how overlap is managed](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Mathematical_Definition_STFT.html#19930).